# How to center logo in mobile view?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I have been trying to center the logo in mobile view < 991px .. but no luck.

Website : http://test.themesresponsive.com

I tried the following : margin:auto and margin-left: 50%

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this css code to the .logo container

```
float: none;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: That worked great - thanks!!

I have implemented the css code on the website.

Is there anyway to minus 30px to the left to account for the menu toggle - so the logo is truly centered on the screen?

Something like : justify-content: (center-30px); ?

Comment: The easy way to do this is to add padding-right: 30px; to the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this for resolution smaller or equal to 1120px

```
@media (max-width: 1120px) {
  div.logo span,
  div.logo a {
    display: block;
    width: 50%; /* width and max-width of logo */
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-right: auto; /* margin auto to centrer logo */
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  div.logo a img {
    width: 100%;  /* full width within anchor */
    height: auto; /* keep aspect ratio of logo */
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome .. Thanks guys.

I found the following code worked best : 

.btMenuVertical .btLogoArea .logo {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    max-width: 230px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}